# Need help targeting specific characters in a column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select a column using SQL but with a condition that would ignore all values in the column that have the 4th character of the value as 0.

For example,

my Column is called promos, and the stored values are W080045678, I want this value to be ignore since the 4th character is a 0 in the string.

What is the condition that I can add?

I have tried

```
AND promos <> '__'0%'
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `NOT LIKE`:

```
and promos not like '___0%'
```